# Mobile to mobile (android) communication over the internet via a server

Tags: android, networking, communication

So, i am working on a project that needs to accomplish a message transfer between 2 mobiles (android application) over the internet which will but obvious require a (relay) server on which both the clients can open connections. I have been looking for this all over the place, through hole punching, GCM, and somewhere it was written that hole punching is **NOT** possible in 3G networks because of the sophisticated NATs that we have in market today.

A good resource on where exactly can i find the solution to my problem of peer to peer communication would be highly appreciated.

A prior experience in the field mentioned above can fetch you a partner's role in the project. I assure that the idea is great and worth working on.

Thanks a lot for reading. Awaiting response.

Answer (score 0):

GCM or your own XMPP implementation would be the way to go here.  Basically your server has an API setup that a device can connect to which takes in some data and triggers a push notification to be sent to the second device.  GCM works well because the app does not need to be running on the device that needs to receive the notification.  XMPP works well if you only care about the message occurring when the app is running and you require all network communication to be on the same network (GCM uses outside servers under Google's control).

Comment: Can you please suggest a reference for good documentation and example of XMPP?

Comment: Smack is a standard library for XMPP implementations in Android.  See https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/

Comment: Any suggestions on what should be used for implementing xmpp on the server side.

Comment: There's a few different solutions.  If you're on a Ubuntu server, check out ejabberd.  https://www.ejabberd.im/

Comment: So, while sending a message to a person, we use the username as a key to send the message to that particular person.?

Comment: Yes - you send a message to a user using their "handle" on the xmpp server.  You'll have to design the system such that the devices know each other's handles